# QT Changing pixmap each frame

Tags: c++, qt

I just started working in QT, and I am trying to change some pixel colors of pixmap each frame.

```
QGraphicsScene *graphic = new  QGraphicsScene(this);
QPixmap LifeMap=QPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(LifeGrid));
```

this is my graphic scene and my pixmap declaration.

So in a function that i call each frame i use this  line of code to update pixmap

```
graphic->addPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(LifeGrid));
```

and it workes, but every few seconds i have less and less ram memory. After my memory is full my computer stopes working and i cant do anything.
(i guess it has something to do with addPixmap function, because it declars a whole new pixmap)

So is there a function that would allow me just to update this graphic, or change pixmap?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well yes, `addPixmap` just adds the new pixmap on top of the scene, so the older pixmaps never get removed and you ran out of memory sometime soon. but I thought you just wanted to change some pixels, not add another pixmap every frame!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a function that would allow me just to update this graphic, or change pixmap?

Yes. You have to use a single pixmap item instead of creating a new one each time the pixmap changes. You can also hold on to the scene and the item by value, saving on an extra layer of indirection and leveraging the C++ compiler to do all the memory management for you automatically:

```
class MyClass : ... {
  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
  QGraphicsPixmapItem m_pixmapItem; // must be after m_scene: in C++ this order matters!
  ...
}

MyClass::MyClass() {
  ...
  m_scene->addItem(&m_pixmapItem);
}

void MyClass::myMethod() {
  m_pixmapItem.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(LifeGrid));
}
```